# Can I use predicates from my Domain Model in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, domain-driven-design

I've got a class with a `bool` method, e.g.:

```
public bool IsInFuture()
{ return this.Date > DateTime.Now; }
```

And I store it in a database using EF Code First. If I'll try to use that predicate in Linq operations, I'll get an exception, as it can not be translated into SQL:

```
await context.Where(order => order.IsInFuture()).ToListAsync();
```

That predicate's logic can be rather complicated and I wouldn't like to duplicate it in my code. It there any way I can "inline" it's code into Linq operations? I'm pretty sure, this problem has a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does this need to be a bool method? It looks to me just a return property then you can use this in you linq await context.Where(order => order.IsInFuture).ToListAsync();

Comment: Then I'll need to store this properties in a database. And I need them to be computed.

Comment: You can't use custom functions. You can use expressions, but they have to be translatable to SQL.

Comment: You can annotate with [NotMapped] on the entity class

Comment: @IvanStoev, sure, my predicate methods are promised to be translated to SQL. Is there any good solution using expressions?

Comment: It depends on what do you consider to be "good". IMO there is no other way than duplicating the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the predicate directly. How should EF know how to convert it into an SQL WHERE statement?

You have a few alternatives:

- Rephrase the query to use standard operations, e.g. smaller-than. This will duplicate the logic from the predicate, though.
- Use a raw SQL query. This will also duplicate the logic, but in SQL.
- Load the entire list of entities and then filter in-memory (i.e. `Where()` after `ToList()`). Like this, you can reuse the predicate. **Note that this only a good idea for very small data sets.**

Comment: I have an idea to force the predicate function to be inlined. In theory this should help. I'll try to do it in several days. Maybe someone has an expirience and can share it?